# How to write function to extract n+1 column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a excel file with 200 columns. The first column is no. of visits, and other columns are the data with number of people for that number of visits

[Visits A   B  C  D
2      10  0 30 40
3      5   6  0  1
4      2   3  1  0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2ivj.png)

I want to write a function so that I have multiple dataframes with Visit column and A; visit column and B, and so on (I want to write a function, as the number of columns will increase in the future and I want to automatize the process). Also, I want to remove the data with 0.

Desired output:

dataframe 1:

[visits A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpQa6.png)

dataframe 2:

[Visits  B
3       6
4       3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZRKJ.png)

This is my first question. So sorry, if it is not properly framed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post tables and dataframes using the code syntax editor, and not as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html):

```
for i,col in df.set_index('visits').items():
    print(col[col.ne(0)].to_frame(i).reset_index())
```

You can create a dict to save by the name of columns

```
dfs={i:col[col.ne(0)].to_frame(i).reset_index() for i,col in df.set_index('visits').items()}
```